# Do "rundown" and "lowdown" mean the same?

Tags: word-difference

Do they both mean a brief version? 
Eg.

> They gave us the _ version of what had happened so far.

And is "break down" related to these words? 
Like in breaking down the steps for an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very similar, but have slightly different goals. Both involve a transfer of needed information.

Rundown is a high-level list, helping a person who just entered the situation to be better acclimated to what is going on without being bogged down with details. "He came to the ballgame late, so I gave him the rundown of the score and batting order."

Lowdown implies privately-held and true knowledge that's being held from the general populous for whatever reason. This is often accompanied by a lowering (quieting) of the voice, as if to convey a secret. "Everyone thought that Jimmy painted the mural, but Jane gave me the lowdown: it was actually her."

Answer (score 0):

It seems so according to Oxford Dictionary

[**rundown**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rundown)

> An analysis or **summary** of something by a knowledgeable person.

[**low-down**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/low-down)

> informal
>
> The true facts or **relevant information** about something.

[**summary**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/summary)

> A brief statement or account of the **main points** of something.

[**rundown synonyms**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/rundown):

> [informal] **low-down**, recap

Comment: However, **keep it on the lowdown** means something different: keep it a secret. Although the specific words have similar definitions, they can mean something else in certain contexts.

Comment: @JasonBassford I didn't know that expression. But are you sure about it? I have found this: A phrase used by an adult attempting to use young slang, while failing to realize that the correct phrase is "down low" https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lowdown

Comment: Yes, there is also *down low*. I've heard both. (I don't use either, myself.) I find it humorous that the Urban Dictionary would talk about "correct" slang. In one sense, no slang is "correct." However, I think both are used and understood. (That dictionary had another funny meaning for the word: *Can mean COOL or be an expression of approval. Alternativley an expression of contempt.*)